# Graphic magic returning transparent image

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

Hrllo

I am using graphic magic, but it is returning transparent image to me .

here is my code

```
var croppedImage = gm(request(fileDetails.url));
croppedImage =  croppedImage.coalesce().quality(50).transparent('WHITE').flatten().compress('JPEG');
```

I am using graphic magic with nodejs
Any idea

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, but fileDetails.url probably contains an URL but gm expects a local Path...